# Get column type from schema in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, schema

I'm getting some columns from various tables within my project and would look to obtain some additional information other than the column name, I'd like to get the column type as well.

I'm usign the `Schema::getColumnListing()` method and am passing a table into it, I'm able to get the fields, but not the types?

My code returns a list of tables, and columns along with an `isChecked` state, for purposes at a later stage.

```php
foreach ($tables as $table => $data) {
  $cols = Schema::getColumnListing($table);
  $colsWithFields = [];

  foreach ($cols as $key => $column) {
    array_push($colsWithFields, [
      'field' => $column,
      'type' => '', // somehow get type??
      'isChecked' => false
    ]);
  }

  $tables[$table]['isChecked'] = false;
  array_push($tables[$table]['columns'], $colsWithFields);
}
```

I did see that there's a `getType()` method if I use `getDoctrineColumn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getColumnType` from `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema` class which takes table name and column name as input

As per your code it would look like

```
array_push($colsWithFields, [
  'field' => $column,
  'type' => Schema::getColumnType($table,$column),
  'isChecked' => false
]);
```